# Invoice PDF layout not showing proper Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

There are more than 15 custom option for my each product. When I print the PDF for invoice or order then it does not showing properly. Please check the attached screenshot.

Have you guys any idea how to remove that blank space from the pdf file?
You can download the pdf file from below link,

https://ufile.io/wu6dz

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you found any solution, i'm also facing same issue.

Comment: With 15 custom options it might be better to remove them from the invoice pdf. Without the custom options the white space would disapear automagically

Answer (score 1):

As i see PDF second page content is not fit in your first-page hance PDF writer add a new page and full content is add in that newly added page that's why the first page shows Blank Content and second-page show content.
Please do some counter type logic and add page after some counter limit it will solve your problem.